# Can't import package

Tags: java, import, directory, package

I've been through 10 guides on how to manage correct directory and packaging, and i just cant get it right.

i have my projects in C:\Users\gusta\Documents\Programmer

[image]

in the testprojektclass i have:

```
package testprojektclass;

public class myClass 
{
    private int age ;
    public void setAge (int age)
    {
       this.age = age ; 
    }
}
```

and in the testprojekt main:

```
import testprojektclass.*;
public class importtest
{
   public static void main (String []args)
   {
       myClass youngfella = new myClass();
       youngfella.setAge(14);
   }
}
```

I feel like i've tried everthing, but it keeps saying:
package testprojektclass does not exist..

Comment: actually ***testprojektclass*** must be a child folder of ***testprojektmain***

Comment: o another project that you can use/reference as lib

Comment: this is very basic stuff. Just read some tutorials, or follow the explanations given in the duplicated question. Your folder structure must match your package names. That is all there is to this.

Comment: i just feel like i've tried enough tutorials, they only explain how to package, not how to structure

Comment: thanks alot, the child folder thing worked. So what if i want to package and its not a child folder?

Comment: you have to add the project into your **class path**. if you did it properly then you can import the classes.

Comment: Okay so i've read up on class path and now im even more confused. I wish to have a class that my other projects can import from, there doesn't seem to be a single simple explanation out there for this problem.

Comment: So i've made it work the way ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ said i should. This way i have to have the imported package as a child folder in aaaalll the projects i wish to import the package in, this doesn't make much sense either, as i would have duplicate files all over my projects